Why does Knuckles say "This place looks familiar"?
In some levels of Sonic Adventure 2, when playing as Knuckles there will be a small blue and brown box with footprints on top. If I stand on them, Knuckles will say "This place looks familiar!"
Why does Knuckles say that? What is the purpose of these boxes?


These altars (which appear in every character's levels) can be interacted with using the Mystic Melody item.  Knuckles's is hidden in the Wild Canyon level.
Using the Mystic Melody at the altar will make items appear or another path open up.

So, the cue is used as a hint?

Everyone says something; I don't think it's a hint as much as an acknowledgement that you can do something here, but the character doesn't know what.

Exal's answer describes the purpose of the Ancient Ruin from a gameplay perspective.
As for the other half of the question, the Ancient Ruins look familiar to Knuckles because they appear to match the style and architecture of the ancient Echidna tribe that Knuckles belongs to.
For instance, compare the Ancient Ruin from Sonic Adventure 2:

...to the Perfect Chaos wall mural from Sonic Adventure 1; notably the same Chaos Emerald motif.

Furthermore, the Ancient Ruin's square structure with the four "stairs" leading up to the middle may also be a reference to the temple in the Mystic Ruins, also from Sonic Adventure 1:

The use of blue-and-white stones (crystals?) as highlights in ancient architecture is also a familiar sight from Sonic Adventure 1:

Knuckles' comment is simply a nice worldbuilding/continuity touch indicating that he has encountered similar-looking things in the past, hinting that they are somehow connected to his tribe and - as it later turns out -

 the Chao.

